# Coding theory exercice

Tags: coding-theory

Let's supose that C is the code which contain all the words from $\mathbb{Z}_2^n$ that has a pair number of $1$'s. Which are the C parameters?

Testing in some $n$ I got that for any $n$ we have (n,$2^{n-1}$,2). The longitued of the words and the C distance is obvious, but I don't know how to prove that the amount of words is $2^{n-1}$. Any idea?

Comment: Freely choose the first $n-1$ digits.  You have $2^{n-1}$ ways to do this.  Given these first $n-1$ choices, you have only one choice for the final digit in order to make the number of $1$'s even.

Comment: @JMoravitz: Could be an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: @paw88789 You right.